# PGFplots axis legend with multiple columns/rows of different lengths

Tags: pgfplots, legend

I have an `axis` environment in `PGFplots` with multiple graphs which 
correspond to certain group of data types. I want to stress this 
distinction by grouping the legend entries. In particular, using a 
legend with multiple columns. However, the different groups do not each 
have the same number of graphs, which would result in multiple columns 
of different lenghts in the legend. But how do I do this in `PGFplots`?

For example, how do I get a legend like

```
1 3 4
2   5
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This can be done by using the commands `\addlegendimage{empty legend}` 
and `\addlegendentry{}`.

You have 5 graphs divided among 3 groups and the legend numbering 
increases in the vertical direction. Try

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[legend columns=2,transpose legend]
            \addplot[domain=0:1] {x};\addlegendentry{1};
            \addplot[domain=0:1] {x^2};\addlegendentry{2};
            \addplot[domain=0:1] {x^3};\addlegendentry{3};

            % Add empty legend to fix the legend layout.
            \addlegendimage{empty legend}
            \addlegendentry{}

            \addplot[domain=0:1] {x^4};\addlegendentry{4};
            \addplot[domain=0:1] {x^5};\addlegendentry{5};          
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

For multiple legend rows of different lengths, the trick is similar. 
Simply use the empty legend entries, possibly in combination with 
`transpose legend`.

The result looks like

[image]

Comment: Nice! Could you add an image showing the output of the code?

Comment: @Jake Yes, I just added a picture for the sake of completeness.

Comment: Nice solution! I would like to do something similar (essentially a two-column transposed legend with four entries on the right and three entries on the left side). The problem is that I use a for loop to include the plots, so sneaking in an empty legend entry is not so easy here. Is there another possibility?

Comment: @riddleculous Can't you split the `for` loop or add an `if` statement within the `for` loop to add the `\addlegendentry{}`?

Comment: @Adriaan: An if statement would be a bit ugly since it will shift the iteration index by one. But splitting the for loop is much nicer in my case. I didn't think of this, thanks for suggesting it!